# How to specify a Snort rule connection duration?

Tags: network, attack-prevention, ids, snort, timing-attack

Is it even possible to specify into a snort rule the duration of a connection?

For example: in this format Hour, Minute, Second

H, M, S = 0, 2, 1

If a connection that has the duration of 2 minutes and 1 second, then alert.

Or in this sense:

If a connection is longer than 10 seconds, then alert.

How do we implement the idea?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: If you've got coding chops, you basically need to add a new detection keyword that acts almost exactly like the threshold keyword, except it alerts for any packets after s seconds, rather than c packets within s seconds.  This might be appealing if you're already building your sensors from source in your infrastructure.  Not that hard -- a number of years ago, I rigged up a build for a customer that would actively reset brute force attacks from a given IP once reaching c count in s seconds.